# Having a clickable element in a Bootstrap accordion header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use an accordion and have a checkbox inside of a header. However, when I click a checkbox in an accordion header, it collapses or expands the accordion. Is there a way to click the checkbox without the accordion expanding/collapsing?

Comment: Try adding this css: .accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle { display: inline-block; }

Comment: Ah, thanks! I moved around my checkbox and now it's what I wanted.

Comment: Could you please post some code. I can't get it work.

Answer (score 7):

The click bubbles up to the accordion header, so another possibility (besides moving the checkbox outside the toggle as suggested by others) is to stop the bubbling.

Use some JQuery like:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

or with a shorter checkbox selector:

```
$(":checkbox").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: is there a angular way of doing the same ?

Comment: I am a bit late, but there is a way: ``ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"``

Answer (score 6):

You have to place the *checkbox* outside the *accordion-toggle* but inside the *accordion-heading* class,
i.e.,

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box"/>
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionParent" href="#collapseone">
        <p>Heading1</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

and add the css `.accordion-heading a.accordion-toggle { display: inline-block; }`