# Checkbox in header for angular-ui bootstrap accordion directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm still pretty new to angular, so this may be a basic question, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

How do I put a checkbox (bound to a property of my model) into a header for an angular-ui accordion? I can get the checkbox in there, but the click never seems to get to it, i.e., it never gets "checked".

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
    <accordion-heading>
      <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          ng-model="group.checked" 
          ng-click="checkboxClick(group, $event)" />
      Title
    </accordion-heading>
    {{group.content}}
  </accordion-group>    
</accordion>
```

According to this [jQueryUI accordion with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426425/jqueryui-accordion-question), I can get something like the desired behavior with the standard jquery-ui accordion by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the click event, but that doesn't seem to work with the angular-ui accordion directive.

See this plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QMnaXJeMagrTPRjbIZbL?p=preview.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="group.open">
    <accordion-heading>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="group.checked" ng-click="checkboxClick(group, $event)" />
      {{group.title}}
    </accordion-heading>
    {{group.content}}
  </accordion-group>
```

And:

```
$scope.checkboxClick = function(group, $event){
  $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YQ4Jp6lwQjSngN3QeRBx?p=preview)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - the checkbox never changes state. See http://plnkr.co/edit/tTGy9grHIByb8THbSz9W?p=preview.

Comment: My fault, I meant ng-checked. You are also going to need a timeout in your click event. You can use $timeout for this. I edited my answer and gave you an example.

Comment: OK, that was it. A few minor tweaks and I got it working how I wanted. See http://plnkr.co/edit/O2p0Dj9RZvpXDlao6RLd?p=preview. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `checkboxClick(group, $event)` method change `e.preventDefault();` to `$event.preventDefault();`.

See also [Betty St](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595152/betty-st)'s comment on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158926/641833)

Answer (score 0):

Add

> ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"

like given Below

```
<uib-accordion>
    <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
         <input id="Checkbox1" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" type="checkbox" /> I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
  </uib-accordion>
```